# Django self-referential class for most similar car

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

Let's say I have a class `Car` with a number of fields describing its features. I call and display these features in my html using `{{ object.price }}` etc.

With a nearest neighbor algorithm I have calculated a list of most similar cars for each car and would like to be able to display features of for example the five most similar cars.
Want kind of field should I use for `most_similar_cars` in my class? Please note that the relationship is not symmetric. I.e. while car B might be the nearest neighbor of car A, car A is not necessarily the nearest neighbor of car B. I also need to be able to differentiate between the most similar, second most similar, third most etc.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Car(models.Model):
    """A model of a bureau."""
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    most_similar = ?

    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_model
```

I really hope someone can help. Thank you co much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want asymmetrycal M2M with custom relation model for ordering nearest cars.
In your case:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    """A model of a bureau."""
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    most_similar = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, through='CarRelation')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_model


class CarRelation(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    close_car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='nearest_cars')
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order',)
```

Then you can add relations like this:

```
a = Car.objects.create(car_model='A')
b = Car.objects.create(car_model='B')
relation = CarRelation.objects.create(car=a, close_car=b, order=1)
```

More info in Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

Comment: You'll probably also want to add some `unique_together` constraints on the through model.

Comment: @solarissmoke could you explain why and how? I had the understanding that a ManyToManyField cannot be included in unique_together.

Comment: @Wessi I meant you should add some `unique_together` contraints in the through model itself, e.g., `('car', 'close_car', 'order')` so that you ensure that rankings are unique.

Comment: @mikhail-pyrev Thank you so much for the great answer. Can you also explain how to access the feautures of the nearest cars in the template?

Comment: If I got you right, just iterate over `most_similar`: `<ul>{% for car in object.most_similar.all %} <li>{{ car.car_model }}</li> {% endfor %}</ul>`

Comment: I've updated my answer and added ordering to `CarRelation` model, so you will actually get similar cars ordered by default. Also check project [django-ordered-model](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model). It will make things even easier.